# Getting topology destroyed error in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection-timeout

I am using below code for creation of database connection in nodeJS.

```
var client = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var dbase;

exports.dbconnection = function (uname,pwd,host,port,dbname,options) {
        //If connection already exists return it
        if (dbase !== undefined) return;

        //If no db connection exists create one db connection and return it
        if (!host) host = 'localhost';
        if (!port) port = '27017';
        if (!options) {
            options = {
                db:{w:1},
                server: {poolSize: 10, socketOptions: {keepAlive:5000, connectTimeoutMS:30000}}
            }
        }

        var dbstr;

        if (!uname) dbstr = 'mongodb://'+host+':'+port+'/'+dbname;
        else 
            dbstr = 'mongodb://'+uname+':'+pwd+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+dbname;

        client.connect(dbstr,options,function(err,db){
            if (err) {
                    console.log('[SmartBin:dbclient:Server connection to the database server is failed, terminating application server....]'); 
                    process.exit(0); 
            }

            dbase = db;
            console.log('[SmartBin:dbclient:Connection to the database server is established successfully....]'); 
        });

        // If the node process ends, close the Mongoose connection
        process.on('SIGINT', function() {  
            if (dbase) {
                dbase.close(function () {
                    console.log('[SmartBin:dbclient:Application server has been shutdown....]');
                    process.exit(0);
                });
            }
        });
};

exports.get = function(name,query,fields) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var table = dbase.collection(name);
        table.find(query,fields).toArray(function(err,result){
            if (err) reject(err);
            else
                resolve(result);
        });             
    });
};
```

I am able to insert, get values from the database but after some time I am getting Topology destroyed mongo error message. No where I am closing the db connection. The reason for 'topology destroyed' could be because I am trying to insert even after the connection time out period. In my application the database insertion operation happens once in 6 hours and sometimes even more. So if I don't query the database the only operation that will be carried out is insertion operation. Keeping this scenario in mind what is the best solution for connectionTimeout period. Should I make it as 24 hrs or any other strategy would be better. Please suggest.

I am also unsure whether connection pooling is working in this example. I am getting `Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit` message whenever I am starting my server node. I am trying to invoke dbconnection method from 11 different JS files in my nodeJS application.